# sr-speedbar shows compilation warning at startup

Tags: speedbar

In my .emacs I have `(require 'sr-speedbar)`. It works fine, but at startup I always see the compile-log-buffer with `Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable 'helm-alive-p'`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432093/get-rid-of-reference-to-free-variable-byte-compilation-warnings) question it has to be some wrong definition somewhere, but where?

I guess it has to be in the elisp code in the package, but there is also a .elc-File. I am a newbie to elisp, so I don't want to break anything. How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to install the helm package...

Another 'solution' is adding this line to your .emacs

```
(setq byte-compile-warnings '(not free-vars ))
```

Comment: Installing helm didn't solve the problem, so I'll stick with your 'solution'. :-)

Comment: The variable `helm-alive-p` is defined at line 949 of the current version:  https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm.el  If the OP has `(require 'helm)` somewhere before the `defadvice` of `pop-to-buffer` -- which contains the offending code of `...(if (featurep 'helm) (not helm-alive-p)...` then you would not see a **reference to a free variable**.  However, I don't fully understand why you are byte-compiling when you start Emacs.  That is something that normally gets done when installing a package or building, but not every time Emacs is launched.  Why is the OP always compiling?

Comment: This question is for Micha90, not for me (comment the previous message). I don't use sr-speedbar but with a quick try I notice that the library is really compiled at startup... That's strange but it's like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Installing helm didn't solve the problem, so I'll stick with your 'solution'. :-)

Try to write `(require 'sr-speedbar)` after your `(require 'helm)` with many of your *helm* configuration along.

```
(require 'helm)
(require 'helm-config)
;; Your preferred configuration for Helm.
;; ...

(require 'sr-speedbar)
```